# prove that if $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of T then $\bar\lambda$ is eigenvalue of $T^*$

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, inner-products, adjoint-operators

I have to prove that if $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of T then $\bar\lambda$ is eigenvalue of   $T^*$ (adjoint)

I know that $<Tv,u> = <\lambda v,u> = \bar\lambda<v,u>=<v,\bar\lambda u>$

and that $<Tv,u>=<v,T^*u>$

but does this imply that there is a $u$ such that $T^*u=\bar\lambda u ?$

I believe something is wrong here. Any help?

Comment: No, your arguments does not show the existence of such $u$.

Comment: Really? I think that such a $u$ exists by using the fact that the operator $T^*- \bar{\lambda}\cdot {\rm Id}$ is not surjective, and hence it has a nontrivial kernel.

Comment: Is your vector space finite dimensional?

Answer (score 2):

If $Tv=\lambda v$, with $v\ne 0$, then, for all $u\in V$,
$$\langle T^*u-\bar\lambda u,v\rangle=\langle T^*u,v\rangle-\langle\bar\lambda u,v\rangle=\langle u,Tv\rangle-\lambda\langle u,v\rangle=0
$$
This means that the image of $T^*-\bar\lambda I$ is contained in the orthogonal complement of $v$, so $T^*-\bar\lambda I$ is not surjective. What can you say, now?

Of course, the assumption is that the space $T$ operates on is finite dimensional, because the assertion is [false for infinite dimensional spaces](http://at.yorku.ca/cgi-bin/bbqa?forum=ask_an_analyst_2009;task=show_msg;msg=3856.0002).

Comment: I don't understand: why doesn't it work in infinite dimension? We still have the fact that non-surjectivity implies non-injectivity, haven't we?

Comment: @emeu No; an operator can be injective and not surjective in infinite dimensional Hilbert spaces. Did you look at the counterexample?

Comment: Ok I just saw the counter-example, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Your argument does not imply $T^*(u)=\overline{\lambda}u$ because you just showed $\langle v, \overline{\lambda}u \rangle = \langle v, T^*(u) \rangle$ for one specific $v$ (an eigenvector corresponding to $\lambda$).

In general,

$\langle v, u \rangle = \langle v, w \rangle$ for some $v\in V$ does not imply $u=w$. (this is clear if you take $v=0$).

However, $\langle v, u \rangle = \langle v, w \rangle$ for all $v\in V$ does imply $u=w$.